# Using Zurb Foundation, how can I create breakpoints in my grid size without a deprecation warning?

Tags: compass-sass, sass, zurb-foundation

**tl;dr;**
I've implemented a way to *regenerate* Foundation's grid *inside* media queries. But it results in a Sass deprecation warning. Is there a better implementation to accomplish my goal?

**The goal**

I'd like to change the total grid width (thereby changing each column size in the grid) for different responsive break points using media queries.  For example, I want a *small* grid for tablets (with a total width of 768px) but a large grid for large desktops (with a total width of 1200px).  Twitter Bootstrap has a similar implementation, but Foundation does not.

**What I'm doing**

I've implemented a simple way to create my own additional breakpoints in the responsive grid for my project.  *Inside* a media query (for large desktops for example) I change the grid width to 1200px *and then* I `@import "foundation/components/grid";` again inside this query. This effectively regenerates the grid (with a larger size) *inside* the media query for large desktops.

The problem is that I'm getting a deprecation warning from the compiler, and I'm hoping to get some advice on my implementation.  First of all, it's working just great (my css is doing what I want)... But this will break if I upgrade to Sass 3.3 in the future.

**The specific warning**

> DEPRECATION WARNING on line 29 of
>   /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/zurb-foundation-3.2.2/scss/foundation/components/_grid.scss:
>   @extending an outer selector from within @media is deprecated.   You
>   may only @extend selectors within the same directive.   This will be
>   an error in Sass 3.3.   It can only work once @extend is supported
>   natively in the browser.

**Steps to reproduce / code sample**

1. Created a Foundation project
2. Included my own partial named `_theme.scss` and included that in `app.scss`.  (This will contain my own styles and also allow me to override any Foundation things that I can't override in _settings.scss and gives me a cleaner upgrade path.)
3. In my `_theme.scss` I have some media queries.  One example is:

   ```
   // LARGE DESKTOP & UP
   @media (min-width: 1441px) {

       // change the total rowWidth for big screens
       $rowWidth: 1200px;

       // now import the grid partial again and generate a bunch of grid styles
       // with this new default ONLY for use inside this media query
       @import "foundation/components/grid";

       // other big screen tweaks such as a bigger logo image
       #logo {
           height: 100px;
           background: url("../images/logo_large.png") no-repeat scroll 50% 0 transparent;
       }
   }
   ```

The issue comes into play where in "_grid.scss" we use an "@extend" directive on line 29 as seen below:

```
// Creating .row-# classes
@for $i from 1 through $totalColumns {
  .row {
    .#{convert-number-to-word($i)} { @extend .#{convert-number-to-word($i)}; }
  }
}
```

Because this is imported inside my media query I get the warning (above).

So... Any suggestions?  I'm sure my hack wasn't the intended usage of "_grid.scss", but it's the best/only way I can think to do this.  Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`$rowWidth` simply determines the width of '.row'. It would be overkill generate the grid-component twice just to change that.

As `.columns` have their width defined in percent they are always relative to the width of `.row`.  So instead of regenerating the grid, you could simply change the width of row at the breakpoints of your choice like this:

```
.row{
  width: $rowWidth;
  @media(min-width: $breakpoint-large){
    width: $rowWidthLarge;
  }
  @media(max-width: $breakpoint-tablets){
    width: $rowWidthTablets;
  }
  @media(max-width: $breakpoint-mobile){
    width: $rowWidthMobile;
  }
}
```

Comment: You've got it.  I couldn't see the forest for the trees.  I was still thinking in CSS (and not Sass) where hierarchically I was starting with the media query first, and selecting inside. I never thought to put the media query **inside** the selector I wanted to alter. Thank you so much!

Comment: pleasure :) It's a common developer-syndrome, not seeing the forest for the trees that is