# Foundation 4 responsive grid layout for large screens

Tags: css, responsive-design, sass, zurb-foundation, grid-layout

I've used `compass` to create new `sass` project with `zurb foundation 4` framework. My `screen.scss` file looks following:

```
// Reset and normalization settings
@import "normalize";

// Global Foundation Settings
@import "settings";

// Comment out this import if you are customizing you imports below
@import "foundation";
```

Default settings contains following line:

```
$row-width: 62.5em;
```

It means that our grid row has to be 1000px (62.5em) for screens that are at least 768px.

What is the proper way to add one more media condition, which will increase `$row-width` variable up to 75em (1200px) for screens that are at least 1280px?

Comment: I have the same issue, I think I will get back to Bootstrap for now...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create breakpoints for .row in app.scss, like this:

```
.row{
    @media #{$medium} {
        max-width: 75em;
    }
}
```

Foundation has variables for screen sizes that are used for media queries in _visibility.scss, for example $medium translates to "only screen and (min-width:80em)".
I haven't tried it myself yet, but should work.
Also, look at this answer, i just modified it a bit:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14247136/961064

You can find other variables for different screen sizes in _visibility.scss: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation/components/_visibility.scss

Comment: Glad i could help, this was my first answer on Stackoverflow :)

Comment: Hey!! This works very well, but the navigation (top-bar) continue with the old rule, how can I do to fix it?

Comment: Hello, I was playing and I added the `@media` code suggested by you but with the `.contain-to-grid .top-bar` selector and the top-bar works fine.